# Old RubyMine with new Rails - No Rails found in SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine-7

I had an old RubyMine 7.1.4 in Windows and installed new Ruby (3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x64-mingw32]) with Rails (6.1.4.1) after uninstalling the old Ruby completely.

I configured path to Ruby SDK. RubyMine detected it without any problems.

Then I selected "Use other SDK" and the desired SDK in project options.

Now when I run any of project configurations I get an error:

> No Rails found in SDK

although I can run the application using `rails server` without any problems.

I checked many forums and none of the solutions worked, even those on Stackoverfow.

So I suppose, there is a general incompatibility of old RubyMine and new Ruby. Any chance to make them work together or I should spend money on the new RunyMine?

Comment: I would highly recommend switching from a Windows only platform to using WSL. I had so many issues using RubyMine directly with Windows installed ruby (not to mention the issues with ruby gems themselves) and switching to a WSL implementation solved almost all of them

Comment: @engineersmnky: Sorry, this question is not about platform choice. Everything has worked for me a couple of years ago and I was satisfied. The problem is that I HAVE to update RoR version.

Comment: it was just a suggestion not an answer and WSL is not necessarily a platform change but either way best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but rubymine keeps project specific settings in .idea folder, so if you are opening an old project it may still be configured to use an old SDK.

Make sure you are changing the SDK on the project. If that fails you could try deleting the .idea folder (you will lose some settings like any database sources etc but nothing too dramatic. (you can always just rename it to test).

Comment: I deleted this folder. Still no effect.